# Expected value: what is wrong with my reasoning?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, expectation

Here's the problem: I start with $10$ dollars and toss a uniform coin $10$ times. Whenever it is a head I double my money and whenever it is a tail I half my money. What is the expected value of my money after the $10$ coin tosses?

**I know the correct answer is $1.25^{10}=93$ dollars. However, what is wrong with the following solution?**

Wrong solution:

The expected value of tossing a head is $5$. Therefore the expected times of doubling the money is $5$ times. Similarly the expected value of tossing a tail is $5$ so the expected times of halving the money is $5$ times. Therefore the expected value of the final money is $10\times2^{5}\times{1\over2}^5=10$ dollars.

Again, I know this solution is wrong experimentally and the $93$ solution is correct but what I want to know is where exactly goes wrong in this reasoning.

Comment: The payout depends non-linearly on the outcome.  This means that the expected payout is not necessarily  the payout from the expected outcome.  to take a simpler example, suppose you get $1$ if a fair die comes up $6$, and $0$ otherwise.  Then the expected payout is $\frac 16$, clearly...but the payout from the expected roll ($3.5$) is $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in stating that your final fortune is
$$X:=10\cdot 2^D\cdot (1/2)^H$$
where $D$ is the number of times that you double your money and $H$ is the number of times that you halve your money. What you are arguing is that
$$
E(X)=10\cdot 2^{E(D)}\cdot (1/2)^{E(H)}
$$
But there is no law that permits you to apply expectation in this way.

As an aside, notice that $$\log X = \log(10) + D\log(2) + H\log(1/2)$$ so you *can* apply linearity of expectation to correctly conclude
$$E(\log X)=\log(10).$$
But this is not the same as saying $E(X)=10$.

Comment: Thank you. As lulu also points out, it looks like non-linearity is the key issue here.

Comment: @cr001 Right. If the final fortune were a linear combination of $D$ and $H$, you could apply linearity of expectation to obtain your expected final fortune.